# Azure Mobile Service and EF Code First - context has changed error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure mobile service backed by a SQL database. I’ve been happily deploying to this for weeks and manage my DB using EF Code First. Now though, I’ve hit a brick wall whereby any request to the mobile service breaks with an error:

> The model backing the '[yourcontext]' context has changed since the
>   database was created.

The thing is though, it hasn’t!
I’ve tried the following:

```
1.  Re-depoyed the service *several* times
2.  Run ‘Add-Migration’ to see if it mystically picks up any new fields/properties
3.  Run ‘Update-database’ which runs without any issues
4.  Combinations of 2&3 over and over
5.  Deleted the Migration History table
6.  Deleted ALL tables from my DB and re-run update-database, which again completes without error
7.  6 then 3, which recreates the database
```

Any ideas how I can resolve this insantiy?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the Code First Migrations can be executed manually or automatically. I would prefer to choose the automatic migration. You could add the following code to `App_Start\Startup.MobileApp.cs` file for enabling automatic migration as follows:

```html
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Models.MobileServiceContext, Migrations.Configuration>());

Or

var migrator = new DbMigrator(new Migrations.Configuration());
migrator.Update();
```

**Note:** You need to either configure **AutomaticMigrationsEnabled** to true under `Migrations\Configuration.cs` without manually adding pending model changes to a code-based migration via `Add-Migration` or you could just use `Add-Migration` for adding pending model changes without set `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` to true.

Based on your issue, I would recommend you changing the database name and use a new database to narrow this issue, also you need to remove the old migration files under the Migrations folder. Additionally, you could refer to adrian hall's book about [Implementing Code First Migrations](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/#implementing-code-first-migrations).

Comment: Thanks @BruceChen. See my posted answer for how I eventually got it working. Was a combination of what you said above and some other pfaffing about!

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it rather frustratingly by:

1. Exporting all my data out to a query window and saving the results to my local PC.
2. Renaming the old DB
3. Setting AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true; and re-deploying
4. Letting the migration create the database (but this didnt create the table)
5. Setting AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; #PanicModeOn
6. Re-deploying
7. Re-importing all my data

What a farce. Obviously I can accommodate this now but when my app goes into production this would be a MAJOR issue!